# Can't hide a window that's not been fully initialized

Tags: delphi, tform

I have this awkward situation that causes an exception. I've found the problem but the solution is so far tricky to implement for me.

In our application, if a user stays in-active for a certain period of time, the security time-out procedure kicks in to prompt the user the password entry box.

However, whenever a form has a message box displayed during the `FormShow()` event for any particular reason (thing to pay attention here; the `formShow` event execution hasn't been fully completed yet) and the user decided to not click the OK button of the dialog box for a certain time, the security code kicks in and tries to hide all forms so that it can prompt a password.
This scenario will trigger the exception **"Cannot change Visible in OnShow or OnHide"**.

Security code loops all forms using `TScreen.FormCount` and hides them using `TForm(TScreen.Forms[ii]).Hide` individually. Hide procedure will cause the exception, because I think this form has not completed it's loading procedure fully yet.

I've done tests, and if I display a message box after the FormShow() event is executed, the security code works perfectly fine and hides all windows without any issues.

I've tried several properties and window message checking to do an "if check" before hiding forms, like Screen.Forms[ii].Visible, Screen.Forms[ii].Active but no luck so far. The mentioned form will be visible and there's no guarantee that it will be active, and if it's active how am I going to hide other non active forms.  So my question is, which property or Windows message would indicate that a form is fully loaded, or at least it has past the `FormShow` event of any given form that exists in `TScreen.Forms`?

I need an answer to what I am asking please, I need a generalized solution that needs to be implemented in the security code, I can't go through over a thousand forms we have in this giant application and individually try to find solutions to any validation/warning logic exist in those forms.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is to stop showing the modal dialog in the `OnShow` of the owner form. Wait until the form has finished showing before you display the modal dialog. If you make that change, and that change alone, your existing code will start to work.

The question title you chose was:

> Can't hide a window that's not been fully initialized

And so the obvious solution is to wait until the window has been fully initialized.

The simplest way to achieve this is to move your code that currently runs in `OnShow` into a handler for `CM_SHOWINGCHANGED`:

```
procedure CMShowingChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_SHOWINGCHANGED;
```

Implement it like this:

```
procedure TMyForm.CMShowingChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited; // this is what invokes OnShow
  if Visible then
  begin
    // do what you previously did in OnShow
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted a global solution but I think a local fix is the best and easiest one to prevent other bugs from being introduced. This solution though, produces duplicate message boxes and I do not like to create a global variable to check if a message box is being displayed. Need a clean solution, code review process :/ FormShow will be executed twice thus the duplication of message boxes occur. However, this gave me an idea. In the constructor I create and POST my own windows message to the message queue and this way it gets called only once and the exception does not happen anymore.

Comment: Just declare a boolean in the form. It defaults to False. Only show the message box when the boolean is false. When you show the message box, set the boolean to true.

Comment: You can certainly accept this answer as is. It diagnoses the problem and gives you the solution. Obviously I cannot know all the specific details of your code. I don't have it. The key is the concept, as covered by the first paragraph.

Comment: I also don't understand why OnShow would execute twice. That should not happen. It does not happen in my simple projects. Ask yourself why it happens in your code, and whether it is reasonable to expect me to work around that aspect that is specific to your code and is not mentioned in the question. Again, it is the general concept that is key here rather than the specific implementation details.

Comment: Oh yea I thought about it already, but my solution would get rejected for being ugly or messy in code review for sure haha. They don't like global variables. I will accept this as the answer, as you mentioned it leads you to the right direction.

Comment: I'm not talking about a global variable. Just a field of the form. But I do wonder why `OnShow` is triggered twice. That seems odd.

Comment: It's the hiding and showing window forms for security reasons. TForm(Screen.Forms[ii]).Hide and TForm(Screen.Forms[ii]).Show will trigger those events. It might need another look and investigation maybe.

Comment: OK, but your current solution in `OnShow` is just as susceptible. You can certainly post a message as a way of postponing handling. What worries me about that is that the user might be able to get some input into the message queue before your message is handled. Which is why I like the synchronous approach of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

David Heffernan's solution gave me an idea and I solved this issue on my end.

I created following;

```
const
  WM_SHOW_MESSAGE = WM_USER + 1;

private
  procedure WMShowMessage(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_SHOW_MESSAGE;
```

Inside constructor;

```
PostMessage(Handle, WM_SHOW_MESSAGE, 0, 0);
```

And this will have the message box logic:

```
procedure MyMethod.WMShowMessage(var msg: TMessage); message WM_SHOW_MESSAGE;
```